# How do I access %LocalAppData% directory if I'm on Linux browsing a Windows Bootcamp partition?

Tags: xubuntu, files, windows-10, filemanager, bootcamp

I've installed Xubuntu 20.04 without installing rEFind and now I can't boot to Mac or Windows bootcamp. That's a separate issue I'm going to fix. But before I do, I want to backup some files to my external hard drive.

The only OS I can access is Xubuntu. In file manager I can read the BOOTCAMP partition. But how do I access %LocalAppData%. In Windows I would use 'run' or search via Windows Explorer, but in Linux I don't have those options.

The version of Windows is Windows 10.

Does anyone know how I can access this directory?

Comment: Hello. What file system type are the partitions you are trying to access?

Comment: @David It's NTFS, is that what you mean?

Comment: You need to add support for NTFS and mount the drives to access them https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-auto-mounting-windows-ntfs-file-system/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually really easy. The drive mounts automatically; that wasn't the issue.

By Googling it (I don't know why I couldn't find the answer days ago) the file path is `\Users\<name>\AppData\Local`.

You have to press `cmd + shift + period(full stop)` to show hidden folders, and then navigate to it.